# Facebook iOS SDK: login for blocked app gives error - "The Page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable..."

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

My app uses Facebook iOS SDK **2.0** for Sign up through Facebook involving publish_stream params as permissions. Now if a FB User authorizes the application for Sign Up it works perfectly fine. I am displaying the login dialog box in app without switching to safari and store accesstoken and other credentials required.

However, following test case gives errorneous result--

TEST Scenario :

STEP  1 : The same user later on Blocks the application from the app activity on wall. 
STEP 2 : Now he goes to the iOS App and performs the FConnect i.e. calls the login dialog.
STEP 3: User enters his correct facebook credentials and clicks on 'login'.

Result :  The WebView loaded reflects the following error message: **"The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may be broken or expired, or you may not have permission to view this page."** with a Facebook Application logged in.

Can this response from Facebook Server be checked and handled at the client end?

Comment: Hi, have you got any solution on this issue? I also encountered the same dilemma. :(

Comment: hi did u get a solution to this ? I get the same issue in android :(